# Mysql query to get a Mutual friend count and display it in a table in php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a table called `myfriends` with 2 columns:

- `friend_id1`
- `friend_id2`

When someone is a friend of some there will be two records. For example lets take 4 members: 1000, 1001, 1002 and 1003.

if 1000 and 1001 are friends with each other there will be two records: `(1000, 1001)` and `(1001, 1000)`. For the sake of the example, let's assume that 1000 is friends with 1002, as well.

I display the people who are *not* friends with the logged in user (For instance, 1000), and I want to display the mutual friend count next to each one. considering the example, I need to display 1 in front of 1002 and 0 in front of 1003.

This is the part of a code and the query that I use to list all the members with the add as friend button next to the name inside a table.

```
$query ="SELECT profile_name,friend_id from friends
                    WHERE friend_id<>'$friendID'
                    AND
                    friend_id NOT IN( SELECT friend_id2 from myfriends WHERE friend_id1='$friendID')";

$results = @mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($results);

echo "<table width='50%' border='1'>";
while ($row) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row[0]}</td>";
    ?>
    <td><button onclick = "window.location.href='friendadd.php?addfriend=<?php echo $row[1];?>'">Add as friend</button></td></tr>
    <?php
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($results);
}
echo "</table>";
```

I want to display the mutual friend count of each one in between the profile name and the add as a friend button.

Comment: So where are you failing ?

Comment: i m stuck in the query part of addin mutual friend column to the table.i dont know how to get the mutual friend count.

Comment: @koshi18: That seems silly to me. Why do you have a double record of everything? You're wasting (effectively 100% of the) space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   f.profile_name,
   f.friend_id,
   COUNT(DISTINCT m2.friend_id1) AS count_mutual
FROM 
   friends AS f
   LEFT JOIN myfriends AS m1
     ON (m1.friend_id1 = f.friend_id)
   LEFT JOIN myfriends AS m2
     ON (m1.friend_id2 = m2.friend_id1 AND m2.friend_id2 = '$friendID')
WHERE 
   f.friend_id <> '$friendID' 
   AND f.friend_id NOT IN(SELECT 
                           friend_id2 
                        FROM 
                           myfriends
                        WHERE 
                           friend_id1= '$friendID')
GROUP BY
    f.friend_id
```

You can see that its working on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc893/2/0. In order to have the count of mutual friends you need 2 joins with myfriends table, one to get the list of all the friends of the people you are selecting and second to check who of those people is friends with $friendID guy.

Comment: Error code 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(m.friend_id1 = f.friend_id AND m.friend_id2 = '1000') WHERE f.friend_id <'at line 8.Got this error msg.I guess last part "m.friend_id".is it suppose to be friend_id1 or friend_id2 ?

Comment: Yes it should be m.friend_id2, i was also missing "ON". My answer is updated, please check the query now.

Comment: doesnt give any errors but now it doesnt display the list.i have added echo "<tr><td>{$row[2]}</td>"; in the while loop.dont know what seem to be the problem.

Comment: Please consider explaining what your code does. Don't just dump a large query expecting the OP to understand what's going on. What's more, you have an SQL injection vulnerability in your query. For those two reasons (mainly the second one), I feel obliged to downvote. Please don't take it personally.

Comment: Ok @MadaraUchiha will do it. Please do not destroy the world with project tsukuyomi :).

Comment: @BojanDevi: Fool, it's already begun. You are just in too deep to ever notice :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I have added explanation and if he does the $friendID = intval($friendID) there is no possibility of SQL injection. If project tsukuyomi has started than you will upvote my anwser now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is not possible for User 1 to be friends with User 7 twice, (meaning there can not be a row with user_a = 1, user_b=7 and another row user_a = 7, user_b = 1).

```
SELECT IF(user_a = 1 OR user_a = 2, user_b, user_a) friend
FROM friendship
WHERE (user_a = 1 OR user_a = 2) OR (user_b = 1 OR user_b = 2)
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```